# Spring MVC - 2 different web applications that are trying to interact with each other (security)

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-security

We have 2 different web applications that are running on the same tomcat.

webapp#1, webapp#2.

Webapp#1 is connecting to webapp#2 via this service method:

```
this.restTemplate.postForObject(url,
                                request,
                                responseType);
```

webapp#2 is receiving this request in the following controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bla", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseDTO requestSomething(@RequestBody RequestDTO requestDTO, HttpServletRequest request) {

  return new ResponseDTO("Hello");
}
```

Now, we have a security requirement that this controller we are revealing in webapp#2 will only recieve requests from webapp#1.

What are our alternatives in achieving that? Do we have to create a new session in webapp#2 from webapp#1? if so where do the credentials comes from ? should we agree on something predefined? 
Does spring security have any way to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm happy if someone can tell me if there is a special (and good) way for webapps in the same container, but AFAIK these are the options:

**Option 1: Disregard that they are in the same Tomcat**

In other words, do it like the two webapps were on two different locations. For example, you can use [HTTP Basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_auth); it is rather easy do a `ClientHttpRequestFactory` implementation that adds the Authorization header for `RestTemplate` on the client side (webapp#1) and Spring Security has built-in support for handling it on the server side (webapp#2). With Basic authentication, communication can be stateless and no session is required. Only disadvantage is that both web apps need to know the credentials.

**Option 2: Check for localhost**

The idea is that in webapp#2 check where the request comes from. Compare `ServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()` with 127.0.0.1 (or any other loopback address). If you want to apply Spring Security, you need create a custom filter in the security chain. Advantage: webapp#1 does not need any credentials. Disadvantage: Depending on your server setup, this can be unsafe! If a user can open connections on the machine, it can pretend to be webapp#1. Be extra careful if there is a proxy of some kind on the machine.