# 2 Different web applications - how can one recognize \ authenticate the other

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, authentication, spring-security

I have 2 different web applications that uses spring and are running on the same tomcat (maybe later to be separated to different tomcat for each)

My first webapp is a straight forward web application that users can login, create account, and do stuff.

The other webapp is actually executing periodically http requests (rest api) towards the first app.

My problem is i must ensure that these requests are actually legitimately being executed from webapp#2 and not from another hostile requestor.

1) How can i do that? 
How can i make sure in webapp #1 that it must serve only requests from webapp #2?
I don't want to rely on IP address alone.

2) Does spring security can help me achieving this?

3) Does authenticating from web app #2 against webapp#1 via the standard spring security authentication mechanism is a viable solution? (username/pass that is only known to both webapps)

Comment: Why don't you want to rely on IP addresses? Alternatively, you could create credentials for your API calls and give them to app #2

Comment: is it safe to rely on ip? isnt ip can be relatively easy altered?

Comment: Search for Spring Security / REST. For example you can use basic authentication to legitimate your rest service.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21696915/spring-mvc-2-different-web-applications-that-are-trying-to-interact-with-each

Answer (score 0):

For a login you can use a service all form most facing web portal, and once authentication is successfully done than you can transfer on a spring login authenticated page and its pass access for user as well